# Galois rigidity for ℙ¹ with infinitely many punctures

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, anabelian-geometry

A well-known result (due first to Nakamura I think) is that given a number field $K$, and a variety $U = \mathbb P^1 \setminus (\text{finitely many points})$ over $K$, the étale fundamental group of $U$ equipped with the natural action of the absolute galois group of $K$ determines the deleted points (up to projective equivalence).

I have been wondering if something similar might also be true with infinitely many points deleted, rather than just finitely many (likely with some restrictions on how "big" that infinite set can be — it would probably be very bad to delete every single $K$-point). Unfortunately, after a lot of struggle I remain stuck — there doesn't seem to be a straightforward way to reduce to the known case of a finite number of points, nor have I been able to adapt Nakamura's proof to this setting.

Is anything known about this case? Even a counterexample would be interesting.

Comment: What would be the statement? $\Bbb{P}^1\smallsetminus \{\infty$ many points} is not an algebraic variety, its $\pi_1$ is not defined.

Comment: It's a scheme - by fundamental group I mean etale fundamental group.

Comment: How exactly is $\mathbb{P}^1\setminus \mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{Z})$ a scheme?

Comment: I am not sure how $\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb Z}$ can even be viewed as contained in $\mathbb P^1_K$ - wouldn't it go the other way? For the same reason Spec Q[x] maps to Spec Z[x] but not the other way around.

If you mean deleting the copy of the integers and $\infty$ inside of $\mathbb P^1_K$, then this scheme is even affine: localize $K[t]$ to invert $t-n$ for each integer $n$.

Comment: Note that ${\bf P}^1_K$ with infinitely many points removed cannot be a subscheme (in particular locally closed), unless it is finite.

Comment: If the scheme structure in question is that of $Spec K[t, (t-t_1)^{-1},\dots]$ where $\infty, t_1,t_2,\dots$ are the punctures then the statement seems to be a formal consequence of Mochizuki's https://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~motizuki/The%20Local%20Pro-p%20Anabelian%20Geometry%20of%20Curves.pdf Any finite etale cover of this affine scheme necessarily descends to an etale cover of $\mathbb{P}^1$ from which only finitely many punctures have been removed. Therefore, the $\pi_1$ of this scheme is the inverse limit of $\pi_1$s of complements to the finite subsets of the set of punctures...

Comment: Now, if these inverse limits for two infinite sets $S_1,S_2$ of punctures are isomorphic then for any finite subset $S\subset S_1$ there exists $S'\subset S_2$ such that $\pi_1(\mathbb{P}^1\setminus S')$ surjects onto $\pi_1(\mathbb{P}^1\setminus S)$. There must then exist a dominant morphism $\mathbb{P}^1\setminus S'\to \mathbb{P}^1\setminus S$ inducing a surjection on $\pi_1$s. This morphism has to be of degree $1$ then, so we get that $S$ is contained in $S'$ (say, we've assumed from the beginning that $0,1,\infty$ are in both $S_1$ and $S_2$). Ranging over all $S$ this implies $S_1=S_2$.

Comment: @SashaP Why for any finite subset $S \subset S_1$ there exists $S' \subset S_2$ such that $\dots$? Each finite quotient of $\pi_1(S)$ comes from a finite $S'$, but why must all of them together come from a single one?

Comment: @SashaP Or maybe the point is that the scheme itself is a "pro-hyperbolic curve" according to Mochizuki's definition - see the quote "Another way to think of a pro-hyperbolic curve XK is as the result of removing some set
(possibly infinite, possibly empty) of closed points from some hyperbolic curve." from this paper. So the theorem applies directly.

Comment: I am stuck on the same point as @WillSawin about finding such an S'. But it seems not to matter anyway, since Mochizuki's theorem already applies to the kind of scheme that I am thinking about. I do still wonder if Nakamura's method applies (if only because Mochizuki's proof goes way way over my head).

Comment: @WillSawin RIght, thanks for pointing this out. I was implicitly assuming that $\pi_1(\mathbb{P}^1\setminus S)$ for finite $S$ form a cofinal system among f.g. quotients of the $\pi_1$ of an infinitely punctured line, but this isn't obvious indeed.

Comment: Actually, I think I have to amend my previous comment: it looks like the theorems stated for pro-curves would only determine such a curve up to birational equivalence, rather than isomorphism.

Comment: The point is that the map on fundamental groups comes from a birational morphism, but since the map on fundamental groups is an isomorphism, the birational morphism must be an isomorphism as well

Comment: Ahh! Thank you so much.